Failure to initialise MySQL Server 5.7 due to mysqlx_port=0.0
I'm migrating a legacy system to a more recent server and I am having issues installing MySQL Server 5.7. When I try I get the error unknown variable mysqlx_port=0.0. I've tried updating the my.ini file to comment out this variable, or to set it to another value (3306) but whenever the configuration is ran the file is regenerated with mysqlx_port=0.0
Has anyone run into this issue, or does anyone have any ideas to try? My googling isn't giving me much joy
Thanks!
Full init logs:

Saving my.ini configuration file...
Saved my.ini configuration file.
Ended configuration step: Writing configuration file

Beginning configuration step: Updating Windows Firewall rules

Adding a Windows Firewall rule for MySQL57 on port 3306.
Attempting to add a Windows Firewall rule with command: netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="Port 3306" protocol=TCP localport=3306 dir=in action=allow
Ok.


Successfully added the Windows Firewall rule.
Ended configuration step: Updating Windows Firewall rules

Beginning configuration step: Adjusting Windows service

Attempting to grant the required filesystem permissions to the 'NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService' account.
Granted permissions to the data directory.
Adding new service
New service added
Ended configuration step: Adjusting Windows service

Beginning configuration step: Initializing database (may take a long time)

Deleting the data directory from a previous (failed) configuration...
Attempting to run MySQL Server with --initialize-insecure option...
Starting process for MySQL Server 5.7.44...
Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" --console --initialize-insecure=on --lower-case-table-names=1...
TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
unknown variable 'mysqlx_port=0.0'
Aborting
Process for mysqld, with ID 3212, was run successfully and exited with code 1.
Failed to start process for MySQL Server 5.7.44.
Database initialization failed.
Ended configuration step: Initializing database (may take a long time)


I also encountered the same issue when attempting to install versions 5.7.43 and 5.7.44 using the installer.
However, I was able to successfully install version 5.7.7 RC, so if you are not tied to a specific version, I would recommend giving it a try.

This issue is happening due to the installer, you can use MySQL 1.4 installer to install your required version of SQL server.

Mysql Server 5.7.10 worked for me in Windows 11
Here's the download archive:
https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/installer/
